# update query using select statement

Tags: sql

```
update DCC set DRR=
    (select cast((CAST((SUM(EMI)/100) AS DECIMAL(2,2))+CAST((SUM([REPO ARREAR])/100) AS DECIMAL(2,2))) as decimal(2,2))/((TOTAL*35)/100)/0.01 
    from dcc  
    where (CURR_DATE  BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-03') 
    GROUP BY TOTAL )
```

This is my Query i have to store the value in DRR using select query.

> Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Only if the query returns the identical value more times, then `TOP 1` is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

replace the line

```
select cast((CAST((SUM(EMI)/100) AS DECIMAL(2,2)
```

with

```
select TOP 1 cast((CAST((SUM(EMI)/100) AS DECIMAL(2,2)
```

when you update a row's column value, you need to provide a single scalar value to it.

Comment: using TOP 1 it update all rows with one single result

Comment: if you want to update every record, you can do an update query with a join on the key columns.

Comment: but i m updating records from one table only so i can not use join

Comment: sure you can. you can always self join a table using different aliases. the point is here what do you want to do. update all the DRR values based on a criteria, right? if yes, what is that?

Comment: what are the columns in your table? what are the key columns you want to join on? more importantly, what are you trying to set DRR as, in words?